# Unable to set Focus to drop down list using jquery on mouse enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here is my html code

```
    <div id="mnc"> hello
</div>
<div id="slpt">
    <select id="slt">
        <option value="0">Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
        <option>Option3</option>
        <option>Option4</option>
        <option>Option5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#mnc').bind({
  mouseenter: function(e) {    
     $('#slt').attr('selected', 'Option1');        
  }
 });
});
```

here is a working model on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzpN4/)

The Issue:  after i click on drop down list but do not select an element i hover on hello text in above div.I wanted the drop down list to be set to a default Option1 on mouse hover.But its not working.Can any one throw some light on whats goin wrong.

**EDIT:**
Below is the condition when i hover on the hello text.I haven't selected Option4
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is working model of my question
Here is the html code

```
    <div id="mnc"> hello
</div>
<div id="slpt">
    <select id="slt">
        <option value="0">Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
        <option>Option3</option>
        <option>Option4</option>
        <option>Option5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#mnc').mouseover(function() {
            $('select').hide().blur().show();
        });
});
```

here it is in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqFHr/)

Answer (score 4):

you can also try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#mnc').bind({
  mouseenter: function(e) {

      $("#slt").find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
 });
});
​
```

Comment: u misunderstood the Question.i have updated Question.have a look

Answer (score 3):

You don't put `selected="option1"` on the `<select>`, you put `selected="selected"` on the `<option>`

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fzpN4/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#mnc').bind({
  mouseenter: function(e) {    
      $('#slt option:first-child').attr('selected', 'selected');        
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: u misunderstood the Question.i have updated Question.have a look

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
$('#slt').val('0');
```

to select the option.

http://jsfiddle.net/fzpN4/4/

```
$(document).on("mouseenter","#mnc",function(e) {
    $('#slt').val('0');
});
```

Comment: not working.I think u didn't understand what i said.I dont select another option from drop down.I just clicked on drop down list to expand the drop down list and moved the focus to option4, remember not yet selected.The drop down is still expanded on option4 is highlighted.Now i hover on the hello text.But nothing happens.

Comment: @jade Perhaps you were looking at the older version of the fiddle (I missed a dot). Try it now. The behaviour you are describing is occurring, unless I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: no no.Not working have a look at the picture i have updated.Its the condition dat i'm hovering on the Text hello

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#mnc').bind({
  mouseenter: function(e) {    
     $('#slt').val('Option1');        
  }
 });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fzpN4/5/)
​

Comment: @Asad how can you say that? i was writing my answer and that time you placed your answer, i had no idea what was ur answer before posting it here

Comment: @rahul u misunderstood the Question.i have updated Question.have a look

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mnc').bind({
  mouseenter: function(e) {    
    $('#slt').val('0').focus(); // it will set focus on first option.        
  }
 });
});
```