# on mouseenter getting focus of the dropdown elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<div class="channellist" id="channellist">
  <div class="c01" id="c1"></div>
  <div class="s01" style="display:none" id="p_c1">
     <div>channel name</div>
      <div class="programs">
         <div>p1</div>
         <div>p2</div>
         <div>p3</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c01" id="c2"></div>
   <div class="s01" style="display:none" id="p_c2">
   <div>channel name</div>
      <div class="programs">
         <div>p1</div>
         <div>p2</div>
         <div>p3</div>
      </div>
  </div>

  </div>
 <div class="c01" id="c3"></div>
```

Script

```
$(".c01").live("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
    var id=this.id;
    $("#p_"+id).slideToggle();
});
```

On mouseenter of the class c01 i am making s01 to display block and on mouseleave i am making that s01 to display none.

There are 10 programs. I want to select the  program. On mouse enter it is displaying all the program names when i try to see the programs by scrolling my mouse the next div's program are getting displayed

I cant able to select the programs. It is showing next channels programs

How can i resolve this?

Comment: you try this http://jsfiddle.net/uqFHr/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to set Focus to drop down list using jquery on mouse enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398019/unable-to-set-focus-to-drop-down-list-using-jquery-on-mouse-enter)

Comment: Can you please add your current JS code to the question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have added my script

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".c01")).forEach(function(c){
  c.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    var s = c.parentNode.querySelector(".s01");
    if(s) {
      s.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
  c.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    var s = c.parentNode.querySelector(".s01");
    if(s) {
      s.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#c1{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10px;
}
#c2{
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="channellist" id="channellist">
  
  <div class="chanel-wrapper">
   <div class="c01" id="c1"></div>
   <div class="s01" style="display:none">
     <div>channel name</div>
      <div class="programs">
         <div>p1</div>
         <div>p2</div>
         <div>p3</div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chanel-wrapper">
   <div class="c01" id="c2"></div>
   <div class="s01" style="display:none">
   <div>channel name</div>
      <div class="programs">
         <div>p1</div>
         <div>p2</div>
         <div>p3</div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  </div>
 <div class="c01" id="c3"></div>
```

I had to add a wrapper around each associated `c01` and `s01` (I gave them the `channel-wrapper` class but it is not used). If you don't want that, you can add a `data-*` attribute (e.g. `data-index`) in the `s01`s so that you can linked them with the associated `c01`.
You can try to retrieve it by looking at the following siblings (but I wouldn't do that).